# How do I automatically set a directory and create a new file in java?

Tags: java, file-io, io

I made a program for work that can run on multiple pcs. However, the location of the file that is required to run the program(a data file containing employee phone numbers and addresses) is different for each computer. For now I have to compile and save a different version of the program for each user, which takes awhile. 
Is there a way for my program to search for the specified file name in the users folder, and or create an empty file automatically if no such file exists yet?

Comment: Is it ok to save file in your working directory

Comment: Yes, it would be beneficial actually.

Comment: Compiling different versions for one application, just because of the location of a required file is very bad practice.

Comment: I know, that's why I'm trying to figure out how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  try {

    String filename = "newFile.txt";
    String workingDirectory = System.getProperty("user.dir");

    //****************//

    File file = new File(workingDirectory, filename);

    //****************//

    System.out.println("Final filepath : " + file.getAbsolutePath());
    if (file.createNewFile()) {
        System.out.println("File is created!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("File is already existed!");
    }

  } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

For more details go through URL http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-construct-a-file-path-in-java/

Comment: How do I prevent it from clearing the data from the old file?